# How to put easing into a scroll bound function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, scroll

I'm trying to make a vertical scroll. On this HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="flex-caption">  
    <div>
        <p>.........</p>
        <h1>..........</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-caption">  
    <div>
        <p>.....</p>
    <h1>...........</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-caption">  
    <div>
        <p>.............</p>
        <h1>........../h1>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

So I've put the CSS like this:

```
.caption-2 {
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
}


.flex-caption {
float: left;
}

.flex-container {
display: inline-flex;
width: 300vw;
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.84,.01,.25,1.01);
transform: translateX(0vw);
}
```

Then I change the `transform: translateX(0vw);`with his code:

```
var captionCont, captionItem;

captionCont = document.querySelector(".flex-container");

window.onscroll = function() {scrollPost()};

function scrollPost () {

var y = window.scrollY;
var x = y / 20;
var i = x * 2;
animator(i);

}

function animator (y){
var captionCont;
captionCont = document.querySelector(".flex-container");
captionCont.style.transform = `translateX(${-y}vw)`
}
```

However, I want to try and put easing in scroll these elements, so that it feels more like an animation than just scroll. However, I don't want a triggered animation, I want the animation from 1 to 100% to be bound by scroll.

How would I do this? The cubic bezier doesn't seem to do much.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="animation-library.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>Wubbe Site</title>
</head>
<body>



<!-- Page no.2 -->

<div class="full-page" id="page-2">
 <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="fleuropdemo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>

<div class="caption-2">
 <div class="flex-container">
 <div class="flex-caption"> 
  <div>
   <p>FLEUROP / BERZORGT EEN GOED GEVOEL</p>
   <h1> HET GEVOEL VAN BLOEMEN ANDERS VERTELD</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-caption"> 
  <div>
   <p>FLEUROP</p>
  <h1>TITEL VAN PROJECT VRAAG EN OPLOSSING IN EEN MOOIE ZIN</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-caption"> 
  <div>
   <p>FLEUROP / BERZORGT EEN GOED GEVOEL</p>
   <h1> HET GEVOEL VAN BLOEMEN ANDERS VERTELD</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="btn-container">
  <button>BEKIJK DE CASE</button>
  <button>AL ONZE CASES</button>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="full-page">
 
</div>

<div class="full-page">
 
</div>
 

<style type="text/css">

.caption-2 {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: fixed;
}


.flex-caption {
 float: left;
}

.flex-container {
 display: inline-flex;
 width: 300vw;
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.84,.01,.25,1.01);
 transform: translateX(0vw);
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600');

body { 
 background-size: 100%, 100%;
   text-align: center;
   max-width: none;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   color: black;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: black;
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.margin-left {
 margin-left: 6.25vw;
}

.margin-right {
 margin-right: 6.25vw;
}

.margin-top {
 top: 5vw;
}

.full-page {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}

button {
 width: 15%;
 background-color: white;
 height: 4rem;
 color: black;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: bold;
}


#myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
}


#page-2 {
 background-image: url(page-2.png);
 background-size: 100%, 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;

}


.caption-2 {
 color: white;
 height: 70vh;
 width: 100vw;

    top: 10vw;
    z-index: 1;

}

.caption-2 p {
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: bolder;
}

.caption-2 h1 {
 font-size: 80px;
 margin-left: 15%;
 margin-right: 15%;
}

.caption-2 button {
 top: 16vh;
 position: relative;
}




</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

var captionCont, captionItem;

captionCont = document.querySelector(".flex-container");

window.onscroll = function() {scrollPost()};
 
function scrollPost () {
 
 var y = window.scrollY;
 var x = y / 20;
 var i = x * 2;
 animator(i);
 
 }

function animator (y){
 var captionCont;
 captionCont = document.querySelector(".flex-container");
 captionCont.style.transform = `translateX(${-y}vw)`
}
 


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: create a snippet

Comment: Sure! I added one now!

Comment: Why not use something like [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/) from Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you want really also the cubic bezier in your snippet doen't work because you haven't added transition

```js
var captionCont, captionItem;

captionCont = document.querySelector(".flex-container");

window.onscroll = function() {scrollPost()};
 
function scrollPost () {
 
 var y = window.scrollY;
 var x = y / 20;
 var i = x * 2;
 animator(i);
 
 }

function animator (y){
 var captionCont;
 captionCont = document.querySelector(".flex-container");
 captionCont.style.transform = `translateX(${-y}vw)`
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="animation-library.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>Wubbe Site</title>
</head>
<body>



<!-- Page no.2 -->

<div class="full-page" id="page-2">
 <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="fleuropdemo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>

<div class="caption-2">
 <div class="flex-container">
 <div class="flex-caption"> 
  <div>
   <p>FLEUROP / BERZORGT EEN GOED GEVOEL</p>
   <h1> HET GEVOEL VAN BLOEMEN ANDERS VERTELD</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-caption"> 
  <div>
   <p>FLEUROP</p>
  <h1>TITEL VAN PROJECT VRAAG EN OPLOSSING IN EEN MOOIE ZIN</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-caption"> 
  <div>
   <p>FLEUROP / BERZORGT EEN GOED GEVOEL</p>
   <h1> HET GEVOEL VAN BLOEMEN ANDERS VERTELD</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="btn-container">
  <button>BEKIJK DE CASE</button>
  <button>AL ONZE CASES</button>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="full-page">
 
</div>

<div class="full-page">
 
</div>
 

<style type="text/css">

.caption-2 {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: fixed;
}


.flex-caption {
 float: left;
}

.flex-container {
 display: inline-flex;
 width: 300vw;
  transition: transform 0.3s linear;
 transform: translateX(0vw);
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600');

body { 
 background-size: 100%, 100%;
   text-align: center;
   max-width: none;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   color: black;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: black;
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.margin-left {
 margin-left: 6.25vw;
}

.margin-right {
 margin-right: 6.25vw;
}

.margin-top {
 top: 5vw;
}

.full-page {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}

button {
 width: 15%;
 background-color: white;
 height: 4rem;
 color: black;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: bold;
}


#myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
}


#page-2 {
 background-image: url(page-2.png);
 background-size: 100%, 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;

}


.caption-2 {
 color: white;
 height: 70vh;
 width: 100vw;

    top: 10vw;
    z-index: 1;

}

.caption-2 p {
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: bolder;
}

.caption-2 h1 {
 font-size: 80px;
 margin-left: 15%;
 margin-right: 15%;
}

.caption-2 button {
 top: 16vh;
 position: relative;
}




</style>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, great! That is it indeed! Thank :)!

Answer (score 1):

Include jQuery.UI script then your code should look like:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var Top = 
$('body').find($(this).attr('href')).offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: Top
    },300, 'easeOutExpo');

    return false;
});
```

Comment: So like this?



     $( document ).ready(function() {
 
     $('a').click(function(){
     var Top = 
     $('body').find($(this).attr('href')).offset().top;
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: Top
     },300, 'easeOutExpo');

     return false;
     });
      });